# Calculating the bending moment in 3D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, equilibrium, statics

I'm studying for exam week, and I met this problem in my text book. I thought it was quite cool, however, I couldn't arrive at the correct result according to my text book. Hence, I want to present my solution to you, so we can discuss what parts of it that can be improved, or that I'm unsure about. The problem is stated in the following image:

[image]

**My attempt**

Let's form $d \vec{M} = \vec{r} \times d\vec{F}$, for a fixed angle $\theta$. We know that $d\vec{F} = -wrd\theta \hat{k}$. Likewise, we have that $\vec{r} = r(\cos{\theta} \hat{i} + \sin{\theta} \hat{j})$. We can now form our infinitesimal bending moment:

$d \vec{M} = -wr^2(-\cos{\theta} d\theta \hat{j} + \sin{\theta} d\theta \hat{i})$

Thus, we have:

$\vec{M} = \int_{0}^{\theta}d \vec{M} = -wr^2 \int_{0}^{\theta}(-\cos{t} dt \hat{j} + \sin{t} dt \hat{i}) = -wr^2( [1-\cos{\theta} ] \hat{i} - \sin{\theta} \hat{j})$

Hence, $M$ is given by $M = wr^2\sqrt{(1-\cos{\theta})^2 + \sin^2{\theta}} = wr^2\sqrt{2-2\cos{\theta}}$

But according to the solution presented in the image above, this is wrong. Since we are supposed to have $1-\sin\theta$ instead. I tried finding some trigonometric formulas that might help me rewrite it, but it doesn't seem like these expressions are equivalent.

I'd be glad if you could share any tips or hints on what went wrong. This is my first time trying out using integration on vectors, so thank you for any type of feedback.

Comment: Where is your free body diagram? It is essential to get one first in order to make sure you account of everything in your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D problems require 3D solutions. The simplest approach for me is to use vectors and linear algebra instead of vector components.

I was able to confirm the answer given using the following Free Body Diagram

[image: fbd1]

and finding the support shear force $S_0 = \frac{\pi}{2} r w$, and support moments $M_0 = w\,r^2$ and $T_0 = w\,r^2 \left(1 + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$.

Well actually in my convention all my values are the negative of what shown above.

The key here is the force balance

$$ \small \begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
S_{0}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
-S
\end{pmatrix}+\int\limits _{0}^{\theta}\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
-w
\end{pmatrix}r{\rm d}t=0 $$

and the moment balance

$$ \small
\begin{pmatrix}-M_{0}\\
-T_{0}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+{\rm pos}(0)\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
S_{0}
\end{pmatrix}+{\rm rot}(\theta)\begin{pmatrix}M\\
T\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+{\rm pos}(\theta)\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
-S
\end{pmatrix}+\int\limits _{0}^{\theta}{\rm pos}(t)\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
-w
\end{pmatrix}r{\rm d}t$$

with the supporting functions

$$\small \begin{gathered}{\rm pos}(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta\\
r\sin\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix} & {\rm rot(}\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\end{gathered}$$